# Merging multiple similar query

Tags: mysql

I can get the result from multiple but simple queries but I would like to merge them further as sub queries.

All sub queries are going to be similar to this one-

```
SELECT COUNT(count) AS acc1 FROM (SELECT COUNT(table.colname) AS count 
FROM tablename GROUP BY tablename.sumcol HAVING count=1) as access1
```

likewise others will be

```
SELECT COUNT(count) AS acc2 FROM (SELECT COUNT(table.colname) AS count
 FROM tablename GROUP BY tablename.sumcol HAVING count=2) as access2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UNION ALL for get  both the results in  the same result set

```
  SELECT 'acc1' , COUNT(count) 
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(table.colname) AS count 
      FROM tablename G
      ROUP BY tablename.sumcol 
      HAVING count=1)  access1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'acc2', COUNT(count) 
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(table.colname) AS count
      FROM tablename 
      GROUP BY tablename.sumcol 
      HAVING count=2)  access2
```

I have addedd 'acc1' and 'acc2' literal value for a better result reading  but you can avoid it

do the fact you have only a rows for both the query , if you need  the two result on the same row, you can use a cross join  (cartesian product)

```
  SELECT COUNT(count) as count_acc1, T.count2
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(table.colname) AS count1
      FROM tablename G
      GROUP BY tablename.sumcol 
      HAVING count=1)  access1

  CROSS JOIN (

  SELECT COUNT(count)  as count2
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(table.colname) AS count
      FROM tablename 
      GROUP BY tablename.sumcol 
      HAVING count=2)  access2 ) T
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, union all gives the result of each sub query as row. Can you please suggest something that can help me get results as column.
Also I would like to optimize it a bit. (For information all the sub queries run on same table just the having part is different for each)

Comment: answer  update with a suggestion for result on the same row

Comment: For results updated answer is okay. problem now is optimization (just a bit)  because I have about 28 such sub queries. Please see if you can help.

Comment: You are changing your question time by time and this is not  fair..  overall there are not elements for a correct evaluation related  to performance   .. you have not where and join in your subquery so there are not elements for improve performance  ..

Comment: okay then, I won't change questions further. I guess this will do. thanks again for the help.

Comment: yes, my bad ! it's totally accepted and actually I might not need optimization ! total time is near to 4s which is bearable for admins. So many thanks.